# How to share DAO classes between two modules using spring-jdbc template and spring-transaction?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Basically, I need to configure spring-jdbc template + transactions so that two independent modules can use the same DAO classes from the third shared module. Moreover one of them does db calls in auto-commit mode, while another has one method which performs several db calls in a transaction.

```
module 1
   |_____service
            |______TransactionService.class (uses module2.model.dao)

module 2 
   |_____model
           |______ entities (shared)
           |______ dao (shared, built with spring_jdbc JdbcTemplate)

module 3 
   |_____service
            |______ Service.class (uses module2.model.dao)
```

It was pretty easy to do with plain java.sql.* and jdbc, but I'm new to Spring and totally lost at configuring it. Do I need to create a single DataSource configuration class with two data sources (DataSourceDriverManager and DataSourceTransactionManager) and place it in a shared module 2? Or should I make two configuration classes per each module? What is the best solution here?

Answer (score 0):

best solution for do this is using JPA.
for doing this you must configure spring-jpa in your project
see Hibernate too